# Javamail : Not able to send an email with message body, text/html and attachment.

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, multipart, mailer

I am able to get all the message , html and attachment in the mail but the  message text is received as a text file.

I want the message to be displayed in the mail.Any help would be appreciated.

```
     final String subject = "Automation Execution Report";
```

Message text that has to be sent

```
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    msg.append("Hi All"+"\n");
    msg.append("We have executed the Automation Suite in current 
    build."+"\n");
    msg.append("Please find the automation report in the attachment");

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        //below code only requires if your want cc email address
        message.setSubject(subject);
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ 
        File.separator+"test_reports");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
           if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
               lastModifiedFile = files[i];
           }
        }
        String attach = lastModifiedFile.toString();
```

Multiparts created

```
        Multipart parent = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        Multipart child=new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        message.setSubject(subject);
```

Customized report in html format being printed on the mail

```
        MimeBodyPart htmlpart = new MimeBodyPart();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\SVN CODE\\test- 
         output\\customized-emailable-report.html")), writer);
        htmlpart.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html");

        child.addBodyPart(htmlpart);
```

Message text which has to be printed on the mail

```
        MimeBodyPart txtpart=new MimeBodyPart();
        txtpart.setContent(msg.toString(), "text/plain");
        child.addBodyPart(txtpart);
        //Adding the child multipart to parent multtipart     
        MimeBodyPart sub=new MimeBodyPart();
        sub.setContent(child);
        parent.addBodyPart(sub);
        //Attachment part   
        BodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attach);
        attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachPart.setFileName("Test Automation report.html");
        parent.addBodyPart(attachPart);
```

Setting the content to the message

```
         message.setContent(parent);

        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host,25,from, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

      } 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InHyZ.png
Please advise as to how the message text can be printed on the mail
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [MimeMultipart](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) and add [MimeBodyPart](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html) elements to it.

```
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

String htmlContent = "<p>Hello World!</p>"
// add HTML content here
final MimeBodyPart  messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
// HTML Content
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlContent, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");

// add it
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// don't forget to add the content to your message.
message.setContent(multipart);
```

With this method, you can add an attachment as another MimeBodyPart :

```
     String filePath = "/tmp/dummy.txt"
     MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filePath);
     bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     bodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
     multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
```

**EDIT**
Did not see that you were already using a multipart.
Your problem here only lies with the content type you are setting. You must use `"text/html"` instead of `"text/plain"`

Comment: I tried that too and the text comes in an html file.i need to print the string in the mail.

Comment: Have you tried setting appending the message FIRST before the attachment ?